# Unhandled promise rejection when running Angular 6 site in IE11

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11

I've developed a website in Angular 6 and exclusively tested in Chrome and Safari. First time I opened the site in IE11 I received the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: SyntaxError ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: SyntaxError undefined
```

I'm pretty new in Angular and simply have no idea where to start

My **tsconfig.ts**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module":"es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <base href="/">

    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <app-root>
        <div class="loader-container">
            <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
    </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [This might help](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/6386#issuecomment-222885991)

Comment: I already included that shim in my index.html @Maryannah

Comment: Then I don't know, I'm no IE expert, I just remembered this solution. Good luck with your issue, hope you resolve it !

Answer (score 1):

Please check the polyfills.ts file, make sure you have uncomment the related imports for the IE browser. Like this：

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
 //import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
 import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

I have created a sample using above polyfills and your code, everything works well on my side. You could check it, if still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Remove not from below line in your browserlist file.

```
# This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
# For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
#   npx browserslist

> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.**
```

**IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not' from last line and try.**